# Line edittext have space from top

Tags: android

I want to create a line edittext and set it's height match parent but when It display have a space with top as shown in below image.

Here is my code :

```
public class LineEditText extends EditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;
public LineEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#afaaaa")); 
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();

    int count = height / line_height;

    if (getLineCount() > count)
        count = getLineCount();
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

edittext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <app.lichconggiao.custom.LineEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNote"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#212121" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my screen display

[image]

How i can fix it?
Please help me thank alot

Comment: You need to post the complete xml layout. But for starters check where exactly is `rlTop`.

Comment: check height of rlTop layout and put xml file here

Comment: @Vickyexpert@AbbasI added it in new linear layout and it show same.

Comment: Set the `gravity` on your `<LineEditText>` to `top|left`, or `top|start`. Or do it programmatically in the constructor.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you! it true!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();

    //int count = height / line_height;

    if (getLineCount() > height)
        height = getLineCount();
    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;

    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        float f = (float) (baseline + 1);
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: try this, Its working for me,